# GrapesJS: Adding columns does not work on simple example

Tags: javascript

I am evaluating GrapesJS. I installed it like described [here](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs#installation) and added the module "blocks basic" and installed it like described [here](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-blocks-basic). (Simple basic installation.)

On a very simple, empty HTML5 page, I wanted to try things out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/grapes.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="gjs"></div>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/grapes.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/grapesjs-blocks-basic/dist/grapesjs-blocks-basic.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var editor = grapesjs.init({
      fromElement: 1,
      container : '#gjs',
      // components: '',
      style: '.txt-red{color: red}',
      plugins: ['gjs-blocks-basic']
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Everything is working great, but I cannot add any column block. When I drag on the one/two/three columns-elements on the editor, absolutely nothing happens. There is no error on the browser's console. Everything else works fine.

So I guess, I am missing some sort of configuration flag or so?

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The code above works fine, it was an issue with my local development environment. After uploading this sample to http://brokenlande.de/grapesjs/ to share it with the lead developer on GitHub, the code works perfectly fine.